# openMPI Compiler error when trying to create vector of random Integers

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to create a vector of random integers but when I try to compile with `mpic++` it gives an error that leads me to believe my compiler doesn't like the `#include <random>`.  Below is the code I'm trying compile.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map> 

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    vector<int> vec(5);
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<> dis;
    generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](){ return dis(gen); });

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using `openmpi` because it's part of a bigger program that uses it but the problem is with this part of the code.  Below is what I'm using to compile it.

```
mpic++ program.cpp -o program.o
```

Below is the error I'm getting:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/random:35:0,
             from program.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options
```

The gcc version is `gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)`.  Is there a flag I can set to try and compile with that standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as the compiler suggests and use `std` flag:

```
-std=c++11
```

Header `random` is really a C++11 extension. This issue is not related to openMPI.